# Replace references from base class during compile?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, devexpress

I have a third-party library that I inherit from. That library is referencing a old version of DevExpress. When I try and upgrade my projects to use a newer version of DevExpress I get several CS0012 Errors. The one below is one example

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0012  The type 'TableView' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. 
You must add a reference to assembly 'DevExpress.Xpf.Grid.v12.2, Version=12.2.6.0, 
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a'.  ...
```

The newer version of Devexpress that I want to use have the above 'TableView' type in it, so that isn't a problem. But Visual Studio wont allow me to compile my project.

I'm guessing that the base library has the 'Specific Version' flag set on the reference.

I don't have access to the source of the base library.

So, is there a way where I can tell Visual Studio that everything is ok and please compile? To force it to accept my newer version of DevExpress.

I do understand that there can be breaking changes between versions, but in this case I don't think it's a issue. So if I had access to the source of the base library I would update the DevExpress version there and everything would be fine.

**Update**
I have tried to use this in the app.config, but it makes no difference what I can tell. From my understanding the below config only applies during runtime so I still get the problem during compile.

```
<dependentAssembly>
        <publisherPolicy apply="no" />
        <assemblyIdentity name="DevExpress.XtraScheduler.v12.2.Core" publicKeyToken="b88d1754d700e49a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-21.0.0.0" newVersion="21.1.4.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
```

Comment: Did you tried already answered question about redirecting assembly versions ?

Comment: I have now, and i have updated the question accordingly. Thanks!